# "the element of imprecision" and "casual and bold"

Tags: meaning

Ran into this:

> For the hundredth time he resented **the element of imprecision**, *the margin of guesswork that entered into the business*. The project as he had worked it out was **casual and bold**, the risks were considerable.

For context: [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://jameshilston.com/pages/reading/catbird_seat.htm&ei=9CP9Ur-YDsiFogSGwYHAAQ&usg=AFQjCNF0BPhEl-n-I8N5KG-J8Fdlxg1fPA&sig2=szB1M7fwuUpcCWkwLMcUEQ)

1)Is the *the margin of guesswork that entered into the business* the appositive of **the element of imprecision**?
2)Could you kindly rephrase the whole 2 sentences? I mean if you were to say it with different simpler words while the meaning would not change, how would you say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes

2) I don't know about rephrasing to maintain the meaning... It is explaining the discomfort a very meticulous man feels in committing a crime in a bold and risky fashion, so that by virtue of his careful character no one would suspect him.